# Looking for XPath expression builder

Tags: xml, xpath

I am looking for a tool or website where i can paste a xml, and then select a value or attribute and then the tool or website give me  the XPath expression necesary to select that value or attribute. exist any tool like this?

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the [most voted XPath tagged question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath?sort=votes&pagesize=15) in SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) with "XML Tools" plug in.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA also has this feature

Answer (score 0):

Firebug Firefox extension gives you CSS or XPath absolute paths to a selected element. The same in IE is given by IE Developer Tools.

[image: Firebug Firfox extension]

Comment: Where is the option for IE Developer Tools?